# Shorten number of elements in comma-separated strings by vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data with columns such as `Area_bsl` that contain strings of comma-separated values and a column `diffr` that states the number of elements by which `Area_bsl` must be *shortened*:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  Area_bsl = c("155,199,198,195,100,112,177,199,188,144",
               "100,99,98,95,100,112,111,99",                        
               "131,166,155,111,100,117,166,188,101,101,105,166"),
  diffr = c(3,0,6)
)
```

So what I need to do is cut off ...

- the last 3 elements in `Area_bsl` and `id == 1`
- 0 elements in `Area_bsl` and `id == 2`
- the last 6 elements in `Area_bsl` and `id == 3`

I've been approaching this task like this; the last part using `slice_head` throws an error:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  # separate comma-separated values into rows:
  separate_rows(Area_bsl) %>%
  # for each `id`...:
  group_by(id) %>%
  #... create a row counter:
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  # ...create the cutoff point:
  mutate(cutoff = last(rowid) - diffr) %>%
  # ...slice out as many as `cutoff` rows: <--- does not work! 
  slice_head(n = cutoff[1])
Error in `slice_head()`:
! `n` must be a constant.
Caused by error in `force()`:
! object 'cutoff' not found
```

The **desired result** is this:

```
      id Area_bsl diffr rowid cutoff
   <int> <chr>    <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1     1 155          3     1      7
 2     1 199          3     2      7
 3     1 198          3     3      7
 4     1 195          3     4      7
 5     1 100          3     5      7
 6     1 112          3     6      7
 7     1 177          3     7      7
11     2 100          0     1      8
12     2 99           0     2      8
13     2 98           0     3      8
14     2 95           0     4      8
15     2 100          0     5      8
16     2 112          0     6      8
17     2 111          0     7      8
18     2 99           0     8      8
19     3 131          6     1      6
20     3 166          6     2      6
21     3 155          6     3      6
22     3 111          6     4      6
23     3 100          6     5      6
24     3 117          6     6      6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** If we want to omit `rowwise` operations:

We could group:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Area_bsl = ifelse(diffr == 0, 
                           Area_bsl, 
                           paste(head(strsplit(Area_bsl, ",")[[1]], -diffr), collapse = ",")), .by=id) %>% 
  separate_rows(Area_bsl, sep = ",")
```

**First answer:**

First we remove the n = `diffr` from the string `Area_bsl` with `strsplit()` then `collapse` again. Finally we use `separate_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Area_bsl = ifelse(diffr == 0, Area_bsl, paste(head(strsplit(Area_bsl, ",")[[1]], -diffr), collapse = ","))) %>% 
  separate_rows(Area_bsl, sep = ",") %>% 
  data.frame()
```

OR

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Area_bsl = ifelse(diffr == 0, Area_bsl, paste(head(strsplit(Area_bsl, ",")[[1]], -diffr), collapse = ","))) %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(Area_bsl, delim = ",")
```

```
 id Area_bsl diffr
1   1      155     3
2   1      199     3
3   1      198     3
4   1      195     3
5   1      100     3
6   1      112     3
7   1      177     3
8   2      100     0
9   2       99     0
10  2       98     0
11  2       95     0
12  2      100     0
13  2      112     0
14  2      111     0
15  2       99     0
16  3      131     6
17  3      166     6
18  3      155     6
19  3      111     6
20  3      100     6
21  3      117     6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why exactly is `rowwise()` needed here?

Comment: We need rowwise because `mutate()` should modify `Area_bsl` row by row. 
Otherwise it is not possible to manipulate `Area_bsl` with its corresponding `diffr`.
For example `Area_bsl` in row 1 is corresponding to `diffr` in row 1 (which is 3). 
Removing `rowwise` won't work, because R won't know which of the rows it should take for `diffr`

Comment: If we want to omit `rowwise` we could group. Please see my update!

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Area_bsl, ",") %>%
  slice(head(row_number(), n() - first(diffr)), .by = id)

   id Area_bsl diffr
1   1      155     3
2   1      199     3
3   1      198     3
4   1      195     3
5   1      100     3
6   1      112     3
7   1      177     3
8   2      100     0
9   2       99     0
10  2       98     0
11  2       95     0
12  2      100     0
13  2      112     0
14  2      111     0
15  2       99     0
16  3      131     6
17  3      166     6
18  3      155     6
19  3      111     6
20  3      100     6
21  3      117     6
```

Comment: A beautifully concise solution - what's `head` doing here exactly?

Comment: `row_number()` returns a vector of 1:n, using `head()` shortens the vector to the required row numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strsplit` and manage `Area_bsl` as a list-column. Then, just `unnest`. The rowid and cutoff should be trivial using `row_number()`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Area_bsl = strsplit(Area_bsl, ',')) %>%
  mutate(Area_bsl = Map(function(a, b) a[1:(length(a) - b)], Area_bsl, diffr)) %>%
  unnest(Area_bsl) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number(), cutoff = max(rowid))
#> # A tibble: 21 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id Area_bsl diffr rowid cutoff
#>    <int> <chr>    <dbl> <int>  <int>
#>  1     1 155          3     1      7
#>  2     1 199          3     2      7
#>  3     1 198          3     3      7
#>  4     1 195          3     4      7
#>  5     1 100          3     5      7
#>  6     1 112          3     6      7
#>  7     1 177          3     7      7
#>  8     2 100          0     1      8
#>  9     2 99           0     2      8
#> 10     2 98           0     3      8
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

With `strsplit` + `head`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Area_bsl = mapply(\(x, y) head(x, length(x) - y), strsplit(Area_bsl, ","), diffr)) %>% 
  unnest(Area_bsl)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 21 × 3
      id Area_bsl diffr
   <int> <chr>    <dbl>
 1     1 155          3
 2     1 199          3
 3     1 198          3
 4     1 195          3
 5     1 100          3
 6     1 112          3
 7     1 177          3
 8     2 100          0
 9     2 99           0
10     2 98           0
11     2 95           0
12     2 100          0
13     2 112          0
14     2 111          0
15     2 99           0
16     3 131          6
17     3 166          6
18     3 155          6
19     3 111          6
20     3 100          6
21     3 117          6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can expand the `Area_bsl` column, then `filter` rowid that is within range.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> separate_longer_delim(Area_bsl, delim = ",") |> 
  mutate(rowid = row_number(), 
         cutoff = max(rowid) - diffr, .by = "id") |> 
  filter(rowid %in% (rowid - diffr), .by = "id")

   id Area_bsl diffr rowid cutoff
1   1      155     3     1      7
2   1      199     3     2      7
3   1      198     3     3      7
4   1      195     3     4      7
5   1      100     3     5      7
6   1      112     3     6      7
7   1      177     3     7      7
8   2      100     0     1      8
9   2       99     0     2      8
10  2       98     0     3      8
11  2       95     0     4      8
12  2      100     0     5      8
13  2      112     0     6      8
14  2      111     0     7      8
15  2       99     0     8      8
16  3      131     6     1      6
17  3      166     6     2      6
18  3      155     6     3      6
19  3      111     6     4      6
20  3      100     6     5      6
21  3      117     6     6      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, where `sub` + `scan` is used to parse the desired subset of numbers in `Area_bsl` column

```
df %>%
    mutate(Area_bsl = Map(
        \(s, k) scan(text = sub(sprintf("(,\\d+){%s}$", k), "", s), sep = ",", quiet = TRUE),
        Area_bsl, diffr
    )) %>%
    unnest(Area_bsl) %>%
    mutate(rowid = row_number(), cutoff = n(), .by=id)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 21 × 5
      id Area_bsl diffr rowid cutoff
   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <int>
 1     1      155     3     1      7
 2     1      199     3     2      7
 3     1      198     3     3      7
 4     1      195     3     4      7
 5     1      100     3     5      7
 6     1      112     3     6      7
 7     1      177     3     7      7
 8     2      100     0     1      8
 9     2       99     0     2      8
10     2       98     0     3      8
# ℹ 11 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: @TarJae Aha, that's super cool! Honestly I didn't know that since I am still a newbie to `dplyr`, but good that l learn it from you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` in `mapply` to shorten by the given number of elements and then use `tidyr::separate_rows`.

```
df$Area_bsl <- mapply(\(s, n) sub(paste0("(,\\d+){", n, "}$"), "", s),
                       df$Area_bsl, df$diffr)
df
#  id                    Area_bsl diffr
#1  1 155,199,198,195,100,112,177     3
#2  2 100,99,98,95,100,112,111,99     0
#3  3     131,166,155,111,100,117     6

tidyr::separate_rows(df, Area_bsl)
## A tibble: 21 × 3
#      id Area_bsl diffr
#   <int> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1     1 155          3
# 2     1 199          3
# 3     1 198          3
# 4     1 195          3
# 5     1 100          3
# 6     1 112          3
# 7     1 177          3
# 8     2 100          0
# 9     2 99           0
#10     2 98           0
## ℹ 11 more rows
## ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```